# Ten pin bowling calculator with some GUI

Tags: java, swing, awt

Recently I was given a task to implement a bowling calculator from predefined methods:

```
package labs.lab2.bowling;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class BowlingScoreboard extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

  // Attributes 
  private BowlingScoring score;    // the object that manages the score
  private JButton pinButtons[];    // buttons to press telling how many pins are fallen 
  private JButton newGameButton;   // button to press if a new match shall be started
  private JLabel label[][];        // bunch of labels for the score

  //Constructor
  /**
   * Constructs a simple window showing the current score.
   * 
   * @param score a BowlingScoring object containing the scoring information. 
   */
  public BowlingScoreboard(BowlingScoring score){
    super("Bowling Scoreboard"); // Title of the window
    this.score=score;

    // construction of the window
    setLayout(new GridLayout(0,23,2,2));     // Layout-Style defined: 23 columns, 2p distance
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000,300)); // should be large    

    // creating the GUI elements
    label = new JLabel[11][4];
    for (int i=0; i<label.length; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<label[i].length; j++) {
        label[i][j] = new JLabel("-");
      }
    }

    // create the buttons
    newGameButton = new JButton("Reset");
    pinButtons = new JButton[11];
    for (int i=0; i<pinButtons.length; i++) {
      pinButtons[i] = new JButton(""+i);
    }

    // listen to the buttons!
    newGameButton.addActionListener(this);
    for (JButton aButton : pinButtons) {
      aButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    // now put all elements into the window panel 
    // the order is from left to right - from top to bottom

    // first row
    add(new JLabel("Frame:"));
    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
      add(new JLabel(""+i));
      add(new JLabel("")); // empty
    }
    add(new JLabel("")); // empty
    add(new JLabel("Sum"));

    // second row
    add(new JLabel("Pins:"));
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
      add(label[i][0]); // 1st throw
      add(label[i][1]); // 2nd throw
      if (i==9) add(label[i][2]); // extra in frame #10
    }
    add(new JLabel("")); //empty

    // third row
    add(new JLabel("Sum:"));
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
      add(new JLabel("")); // empty
      if (i==9) add(new JLabel("")); // extra in frame #10
      add(label[i][3]); // sum of frame
    }
    add(label[10][3]); // current sum of all points

    // fourth row: buttons
    add(newGameButton);
    for (int i=0; i<pinButtons.length; i++) {
      add(pinButtons[i]); 
      if (i<10) add(new JLabel("")); // empty        
    }

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // close-button behaviour
    setSize(1400, 500); // start with this

    // show time!
    setVisible(true);
    updateLabels();
    updateButtons();

  }


  /**
   * Simplest main possible: Start just one scoreboard window.
   * 
   * @param args not used here
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BowlingScoreboard(new BowlingScore());
  
  }

  /**
   * This method is called by the system when a button is pressed. 
   */
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if (event.getSource()==newGameButton) { // someone pressed "New match"
      score.newMatch(); // tell it the scoring object
    } else { // someone pressed a button to tell us how many pins are fallen
      for (int i=0; i<pinButtons.length; i++) {
        if (event.getSource()==pinButtons[i]) { // number of fallen pins == i 
          score.scoring(i); // tell it the scoring object
        }
      }
    } 
    // update the GUI
    updateLabels();
    updateButtons();
  }

  /**
   * Update the buttons.
   * 
   * The buttons for the players shall only be enabled when the game
   * is not finished. 
   */

  private void updateButtons() {
    // if (for example) 5 pins are not fallen yet it is impossible to score 6 pins!
    for (int i=0; i<pinButtons.length; i++) {
      pinButtons[i].setEnabled( i<=score.pinsNotFallenYet() );
    }
  }

  /**
   * Update the labels.
   * 
   * Gathers all the various elements from the scoring object and
   * puts them into the right place.  
   */
  private void updateLabels() { 

    // which frame is played at the moment?
    int currentFrame = score.getCurrentFrame();
    // now consider the 3rd row: the summed points of the frames
    for (int fr=1; fr<=currentFrame && fr<=10; fr++) {
     //System.out.println(fr);
        label[fr-1][3].setText(""+score.result(fr));
    }
    // overall sum:
    label[10][3].setText(""+score.result(Math.min(10,currentFrame)));

    // 2nd row: the pins for each throw
    for (int fr=1; fr<=10; fr++) {
      if (fr<=currentFrame) {
        int pins = score.getPins(fr,1);
      
        // 1st throw of the frame
        label[fr-1][0].setText(""+pins);

        // 2nd throw of the frame
        
        label[fr-1][1].setText(""+score.getPins(fr,2));
        if (fr==10) { 
          label[fr-1][2].setText(""+score.getPins(fr,3));
        }
      } else { // frames which are played in the future
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
          label[fr-1][j].setText("ft");        
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the main class for it. Also, I have an interface as follows:

```
package labs.lab2.bowling;

/**
 * Communication interface between BowlingScoreboard and BowlingScore.
 * 
 * @author jjj
 * @date 2020-12-01
 */
public interface BowlingScoring {

  // Methods to inform BowlingScore that a button was pressed
  /**
   * User wants to start a new bowling match.
   */
  public void newMatch();

  /**
   * User pressed button that tells us how many pins are fallen.
   * 
   * @param fallenPins number of pins fallen
   */
  public void scoring(int fallenPins);

  
  /**
   * Computes the frame that is played at the moment.
   * 
   * @return the current set (1-10)
   */
  public int getCurrentFrame();

  
  /**
   * Computes the points achieved in given frame at the moment.
   * 
   * @param frame the frame of interest (1-10)
   * @return the points achieved so far in this frame
   */
  public int result(int frame);

  
  /**
   * Computes the fallen pins for each individual throw.
   * 
   * @param frame the frame of the throw (1-10)
   * @param thrw the throw within that frame (1-2) or (1-3) in last frame
   * @return the fallen pins 
   */
  public int getPins(int frame, int thrw);

  
  
  /**
   * Computes the pins that are not fallen yet at the moment (1-10).
   * 
   * @return the pins still standing 
   */
  public int pinsNotFallenYet();

}
```

And here I am trying to implement those methods

```
package labs.lab2.bowling;

public class BowlingScore implements BowlingScoring {
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private int standing = 10; //Количество кегль 10 по умолчанию
    private int currentframe=1;
    private int sum=0;
    int[] rolls=new int[100];
    //roles = new int[21];

    int currentRoll;

    // Methods to inform BowlingScore that a button was pressed
      /**
       * User wants to start a new bowling match.
       */
    @Override
    public void newMatch() {
        // начнем новый матч 10 кегль опять стоят
        standing=10;
        this.rolls = new int[21];

    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
       * User pressed button that tells us how many pins are fallen.
       * 
       * @param fallenPins number of pins fallen
       */
    @Override
    public void scoring(int fallenPins) {
        
        standing=standing-fallenPins; //узнаем сколько кегль упало
        rolls[currentRoll++] = fallenPins;
      standing=10;
        
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
       * Computes the frame that is played at the moment.
       * 
       * @return the current set (1-10)
       */
    @Override
    public int getCurrentFrame() {
        {
        
        currentframe++;
        if(currentframe>10)
        {
            currentframe=0;
        }
        
        return currentframe;
        }
        
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
       * Computes the points achieved in given frame at the moment.
       * 
       * @param frame the frame of interest (1-10)
       * @return the points achieved so far in this frame
       */
    @Override
    public int result(int frame) {
        int score = 0;
        //frame=1;
        //int score = 0;
        //int frame = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < currentframe; i++) {
            if (isStrike(frame)) {
                score += 10 + strikeBonus(frame);
                frame++;
            } else if (isSpare(frame)) {
                score += 10 + spareBonus(frame);
                frame += 2;
            } else {
                score += sumOfRolls(frame);
                frame += 2;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(score);
        return score;
    }
    
    //check if strike etc
    private boolean isStrike(int frame) {
        //frame=1;
        return rolls[frame] == 10;
    }

    private boolean isSpare(int frame) {
        return sumOfRolls(frame) == 10;
    }

    private int strikeBonus(int frame) {
        return sumOfRolls(frame+1);
    }

    private int spareBonus(int frame) {
        return rolls[frame+2];
    }

    private int sumOfRolls(int frame) {
        //frame=0;
        return rolls[frame] + rolls[frame+1];

    }
    //end
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
       * Computes the fallen pins for each individual throw.
       * 
       * @param frame the frame of the throw (1-10)
       * @param thrw the throw within that frame (1-2) or (1-3) in last frame
       * @return the fallen pins 
       */
    @Override
    public int getPins(int frame, int thrw) {
    
        return 0;   
    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
       * Computes the pins that are not fallen yet at the moment (1-10).
       * 
       * @return the pins still standing 
       */
    @Override
    public int pinsNotFallenYet() {
        
        
        return standing; //вернем текущее количество кегль после нажатия одной из кнопок 0-10 причем 0 остается всегда доступным
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    
}
```

The first 2 classes I am not allowed to change. My question is how to count fallen pins for each frame and the sum of the result of 2 tries in a frame? I know that my implementation is bad, but how to do it correctly?

Comment: Scoring in bowling is complicated.  It's the sum of two balls in a frame unless you bowl a spare or a strike.  For a spare, the frame counts as 10 plus the pin count of the next ball.  For a strike, the frame counts as 10 plus the pin count of the next two balls.  Multiple strikes in a row count up to 30 for each frame.  i suggest getting the scoring math correct before you try and code anything else.

Answer (score 0):

### Prelude

I copied your starting `BowlingScoreboard` class and `BowlingScoring` interface into my Eclipse IDE.  Here's the GUI that popped up.

[image]

Surely, this assignment came with more instruction than "Create a `BowlingScore` class using the `BowlingScoring` interface".

Looking at the GUI, I have no idea how to proceed.

I have no idea how the GUI works.

I have no idea how I can test any code I write in the `BowlingScore` class.

### Edited to add:

It took me a while to figure out what the `BowlingScoring` interface methods were doing.  The documentation was lacking, to say the least.

I'm not going to provide the complete code, since this is an assignment.  I will provide code snippets and hopefully, better descriptions of what the `BowlingScoring` interface methods actually do.

I did not write the entire `BowlingScore` class at once.  I wrote maybe 5 lines of code at a time and ran one or more tests.  I probably ran between 150 and 200 individual tests before I thought the code was complete.

I know you were given the GUI, but the GUI user experience stinks on ice.  Running an individual test always took 21 button presses.

I defined these class fields in the `BowlingScore` class.  The `game` array is 10 by 3.  10 frames by 3 throws in each frame.  Yes, I'm aware that only the 10th frame has three throws.  All the other frame third throws are initialized to zero and never used.

```
private int currentFrame, throwNumber;

private int[][] game;
```

The `newMatch` method initializes those class fields.  I initialized all the class fields to zero.  The `currentFrame` and `throwNumber` values are zero-based counts.

One trick I did was to define `game[9][2]` as -1.  This trick came in handy when writing the code for the `pinsNotFallenYet` method.

I created a class constructor that calls the `newMatch` method.

The `scoring` method is responsible for incrementing the `currentFrame` and `throwNumber` values.  Frames 0 - 8 have two throws.  Frame 9 has 3 throws.

The return from the `getCurrentFrame` method is zero-based, so just return the `currentFrame` value.

the `result` method calculates the sum of all of the frames up to and including the `frame` parameter passed in.  This frame number is 1 - 10, so you have to subtract one before you reference your `game` array.

You have to sum each frame and sum all the frames up to but not including the `frame` parameter.

Scoring in bowling is complicated. It's the sum of two balls in a frame unless you bowl a spare or a strike. For a spare, the frame counts as 10 plus the pin count of the next ball. For a strike, the frame counts as 10 plus the pin count of the next two balls. Multiple strikes in a row count up to 30 for each frame.

I wound up writing two private methods for calculating spares and strikes.  Since they are so complex, I'll just post them here.

```
private int getNextThrow(int frame) {
    int sum = 0;
    
    if (frame < 9) {
        // 1st through 9th frames
        sum += game[frame + 1][0];
    } else {
        // 10th frame
        sum += game[frame][1];
    }
    
    return sum;
}

private int getNextTwoThrows(int frame) {
    int sum = 0;
    
    if (frame < 8) {
        // 1st through 8th frames
        sum += game[frame + 1][0];
        if (game[frame + 1][0] == 10) {
            sum += game[frame + 2][0];
        }
    } else if (frame < 9) {
        // 9th frame
        sum += game[frame + 1][0] + game[frame + 1][1];
    } else {
        // 10th frame
        sum += game[frame][1] + game[frame][2];
    }
    
    return sum;
}
```

The `getPins` method parameters `frame` and `thrw` are one-based, so subtract one from both parameters to get the game subscripts.

The `pinsNotFallenYet` method turned out to be super complex.  I probably wrote this method 10 times before I was satisfied with the result.

I'm just posting the code.  I don't think I can explain in words what the method is supposed to do.

```
@Override
public int pinsNotFallenYet() {
// System.out.println("pinsNotFallenYet");
    
    // Test if user keeps pressing the zero button
    if (currentFrame >= game.length) {
        // Game over
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (currentFrame < (game.length - 1)) {
        // 1st through 9th frames
        return 10 - game[currentFrame][0];
    } else if (currentFrame >= (game.length - 1)) {
        int firstThrow = game[9][0];
        int secondThrow = game[9][1];
        int thirdThrow = game[9][2];
        
        if (thirdThrow >= 0) {
            // Game over
            return 0;
        } else if (secondThrow >= 10) {
            return 10;
        } else if (firstThrow >= 10) {
            return 10 - secondThrow;
        } else {
            return 10 - firstThrow;
        }

    }
    
    // Should never get here
    return 0;
}
```

### Tests to verify your code:

- 12 strikes (buttons 10 and zero, except in the 10th frame) - 300 game
- 11 strikes and a 6 - 296 game.
- 10 strikes, an 8, and a 1 - 289 game.
- 20 ones and a zero - 20 game.
- 20 fives and a zero - 150 game.

Comment: As I understand. The player presses a button from 1 to 10 and  instead of "fr"  letters near the pins should appear a score number of button that was pressed. And in sum section sum of those numbers. For each frame you can press button twise.  And as final near the sum should appear total score of the game. I didn't see a full task because I am just trying to help my friend.